# Overclock a Core I3 6100 by BCLK without modified BIOSes?

Tags: cpu, bios, overclocking

I can't find any information about if it's possible to overclock a Core I3 6100 without special bioses (without exploiting the loophole door) through BCLK -but an I7 6700 non-k sure can-. I don't want to do it with such BIOSes because I need the Intel HD Graphics 530.

In the case it's possible to do it, do I really need a Z170 Northbridge to do overclock that way, or a H110 one can do it ?

Furthermore, is it possible to make its BLCK from 100Mhz to 115Mhz easily ?

Comment: The ability overclock an locked Intel CPU depends on the BIOS, the BIOS is what determines if it respects or ignores the microcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer but not directly:

http://www.hardwarezone.com.sg/tech-news-asrocks-sky-oc-lets-you-overclock-even-locked-intel-core-i3-skylake-processor-updated

So, it means OFFICIALY that Skylake (non-K):

- Celeron, Pentium and I3 can't be overclocked at all, even by BLCK (unlike Nehalem counterpart)
- I5 and I7 can only be overclocked by bins (forcing 1 core turbo mode frequency to all cores)

And that only Skylake K can be overclocked by bins, BCLK AND multiplier ONLY with a Z170 Northbridge.

For the maximum bins available your CPU:

- [Core I5 Skylake bins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors#Skylake_microarchitecture_.286th_generation.29)
- [Core I7 Skylake bins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i7_microprocessors#Skylake_microarchitecture_.286th_generation.29)